# Strange result with a simple regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on regular expressions right now and experience a strange behavior:

The following regex accepts `Q-123456-789` or `q-123456-789`

```
params: '^\\q\\-\\d{6}\\-\\d{3}$|^\\Q\\-\\d{6}\\-\\d{3}$'
```

The following regex accepts `R-123456-789` but not `r-123456-789`

```
params: '^\\r\\-\\d{6}\\-\\d{3}$|^\\R\\-\\d{6}\\-\\d{3}$'
```

(I simply replaced `q` by `r` and `Q` by `R`)

Comment: How you are using this regex? by `jquery` or other language? Show us code also to understand it better

Comment: And your question? What weirdness you observed?

Comment: @Manwal I'm using javascript

Comment: @Bronzato show code or make a fiddle please.

Comment: I didn't understand why `r-123456-789` is not accepted by the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because:

`\r` matches a carriage return

but `\q` matches literal `q` only.

Btw your regex is using excessive escaping, it should be **without `\\`** i.e.

```
"^[qQ]-\\d{6}-\\d{3}$"
```

OR

```
"^[rR]-\\d{6}-\\d{3}$"
```

Comment: @Manwal `\\d{6}` actually escapes \ and matches `\dddddd`.

Comment: @Manwal: My answer isn't wrong since OP is using regex as a String where it is required to use double \\

Comment: Yes I'm required to use double \\ otherwise it is not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato: Yes I am well aware of that, that's the reason I didn't remove \\ from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` matches a *carriage return* (0x0D - a non printable character), not the `r` character. whereas `\q` does match the character `q`.

If you want to match `r` or `R`, simply replace them in a character class: `^[rR]`.

Comment: Ouch thanks. But now, how can I match the `r` character and escape this?

Comment: @Bronzato See my edit. Let me know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[r]` for exact match instead of `\r` for expected result

Try this:

```
^[rR]-\d{6}\-\d{3}$
```

Use https://regex101.com/#javascript for testing